# 3D printer emulator

Tags: software, octoprint

Hello everyone I'm developing a system to remotely manage several printers at the same time, using the OctoPrint API.

I would like to know if there is any way to emulate printers to do the tests, because I only have one printer and I would need several, even if they were virtual.

I tried [simrerap](https://github.com/buserror/simreprap) but it seems to be too old, and didn't work.

Comment: An emulator? as in something that accepts the G-Code and runs it?

Comment: (I asked because I have one that can do that, but it is unreleased. I've considered releasing it; perhaps now is a good time)/

Comment: @user77232, I don need that it execute gcode right now, I just want that Octoprint detects it as a printer, to work with the API, read sensors etc etc etc....

Comment: Reading sensors requires executing g-code; octoprint communicates via printers with g-code. The emulator would need to be able to understand and "execute" g-code that octoprint sends to it.

Comment: @user77232, yes you are right sorry I was thinking on gcode only for tool move and print, but you are right all the communication is made with gcode

Comment: it's just serial communication, so you can make simple mockups with a PC or an MCU like arduino.

Comment: @dandavis can you share it?